# Disabling Windows indexing service

Tags: windows-xp, performance, file-search

Does it increase the performance of my old notebook (IBM R50e) to disable the indexing service for fast file searching? I am aware that it will take more time when I search for files without this service, but I need to know how much performance this may provide and how much time I may lose while searching files.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't notice a massive performance gain in regular applications, but if you are running a program with a small footprint it may be more apparent. Windows usually starts indexing when it thinks your computer is near idle (when there is a very low amount of resources being used). I'd disable it regardless, I want every bit of performance out of my computer. For fast file searching use [**Everything**](http://www.voidtools.com/) from voidtools.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, a gui would be a nice change from 'dir \. /s | grep "brown bear"'

Comment: It's much faster too :)

Answer (score 2):

disable indexing and use **[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)** instead and you will actually gain time searching files. desktop search doesn't get any faster.

Comment: @Molly - I started using "Everything" several weeks ago, after reading another post of yours. Works great. Are you saying with this answer that I should now disable "indexing"? Why? Should I also disable it for my other internal drive D:\ ?

Comment: if you don't use windows search, then knock it off.

Answer (score 1):

> The Indexing Service in Windows XP Indexes your files presumably to shorten the time needed to search your hard drive if you are looking for a specific file or part of a phrase inside a file.

By default, this service is set to manual (so it won't start), but when you do a search on your computer, there's that little question asking you if you want to make future searches faster.... so you could have enabled it (it will tell you that you are going to enable the Indexing service when you choose this).

if  you  decided switched off, it all depends on how much files having in your drive

To disable the Indexing service, open Computer Management from Administrative Tools (on the Start menu if you enabled this, or from the Control Panel), select Services and Applications, double click Services, and find the Indexing Service. Double click to bring up the Properties window, and click Stop to let Windows stop the service. Then from the Status type drop down box select Disabled.

[image]

[Source](http://www.helpwithwindows.com/WindowsXP/tune-18.html)